# MySQL Replication Lag Check

Tags: mysql, replication

we are about to replicate our database servers into several slaves in different physical locations.

The company which is doing replication for us, has asked to give them a sql select statement on one of our tables to check lag and latency like

SELECT id FROM table1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

Is it a common practice to check the lag between several instances?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what they want to measure.  To see the *network lag*, all they need is `ping` in the OS.  That should be much less than a second, even to the other side of the world.  (Unless they have a sloppy network.)

`Seconds_behind_master` is problematical.  It is a handy tool for the DBA, but it can be "wrong" for many reasons.

- When running a long query, it shows how long ago the query *started* on the Master.  So, `Seconds_behind_master` will rise as long as that query is running on the Slave.
- If you flood the Master with lots of writes *from lots of connections*, the Slave can get "behind".  This is congestion because of single-threaded Slave, not because of network lag.

One thing it can tell (I think) -- If the timezones are inconsistent, or they don't have a good clock sync (NTP).

A `SELECT` will not propagate through replication, only writes.  So, I see no use for your suggested `SELECT`.

If you are running at least 5.6.4:  `CREATE` a `DATABASE` and a login limited to that database (`GRANT ALL ON db.* ...`).  Give them the user name an password.  Let them `INSERT` into the Master and see what pops up in the Slave.  I think this is what is needed (but I have not tried it):

```
-- Create on Master and propagate to Slave:
CREATE TABLE Timer (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    raw_time TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
    sys_time TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
-- Run on Master:
REPLACE INTO Timer (id, raw_time, sys_time) VALUES (1, NOW(6), SYSDATE(6));
-- Run on Slave:
SELECT * FROM Timer;
```

The difference of the two columns will say how much delay where was -- Including

- A tiny delay between `NOW` and `SYSDATE` on the Master
- Network delay
- Slave backlog (if something was running on the Slave when the `REPLACE` was being replicated; this can be minimized by using multi-threaded replication)

Note:  The `(6)` everywhere gives you microsecond precision.  This is more than sufficient to measure the milliseconds for replicating cross-country.

Note:  That technique won't work if you run with `--sysdate-is-now`.

Point the Company at this Answer; challenge them to top it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems sensible to me that they would want to check the lag between the master and slave. It's one of the key things we monitor here, as if the slaves start getting behind it could be a sign of a problem, it also reduces their usefulness for reads / backups etc.

The easiest way would be for them to run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` on the Slave and look at the `SECONDS_BEHIND_MASTER` value (assuming it is Master > Slave, and not Master > Slave > Slave etc)

Alternatively, if you wanted to limit their access, create a table with a single datetime field. Create an Event every X seconds to update it with the current time, then on the slaves grant them `SELECT` access to just that table. They can then compare the current time to the time in the table. (useful where you have multiple levels of slave databases).